# How can I run Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code with Julia as Interpreter? Within Added Variable Explorer/ Inspector?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia

I want to know how I could run **Jupyter Notebook** in **VS Code** with **Julia** as Interpreter?
I wanted to use a **variable inspector/ explorer** from this package but I cant get it to work.
Is there an even simple way to implement them? Like with Python?
In Short like here?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Answer (score 2):

As of November 11th, 2020, the Jupyter Notebook extension in VSCode now supports Julia out of the box. Find out more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/introducing-the-jupyter-extension-for-vs-code/).